# Is that posible to use two windows form in C# and both windows forms share the same serialPort?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, can-bus

I am using a C# "Windows Form App" to send CAN messages via RS232.

in "Form1" i am receiving and sending CAN- masseges by using timers. Since my "Form1" is quite full, I would like to know if it is possible to use two windows forms while still using one serial port? I will send some of those CAN messeges from "Form2".

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Note:  that CAN messages are sent using a timer.

Comment: Don't put the SerialPort on a form. Put it in a third class (presumably as some sort of singleton) alongside the needed logic you need and use that class/instance from everywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

We did this with two printers and splitted the RS232 cable so it hat 1 output and two inputs.
It only works if you use one input at a time as soon as we turn both printers on you get bad data. To do what you want to do i would look for a better data cable and hardware. I would think with a port switch you could get better results.

Comment: Why can't you build out an IO queue?